# Tomcat Web Application Manager - "FAIL - File upload failed, no file" error when uploading WAR file to deploy

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-xp, deployment, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.5 (installed with XAMPP 1.7.4) on a Windows XP (virtual machine, if it matters) with JVM version 1.6.0_27-b07.
**When I try to upload a WAR file to deploy in Tomcat Web Application Manager ("Select WAR file to upload"), I get the following error message:**

```
Message:    FAIL - File upload failed, no file
```

I tried to upload two different war-files which do work on another machine (and another server), so I think there's no problem with them.

What can be the possible reasons that lead to this error message?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why it didn't work on a virtual Windows XP in VirtualBox, but installing XAMPP with Tomcat on a "live" host machine solved the problem. But it would really be good to know why it didn't work on the virtual machine...
Wish Tomcat's documentation wasn't so poor...